Application crashes when using upload field on view
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application. I've got a view with an upload field (photo upload) that when I click on it and open the file the application just stops and does not show any message error on anywhere. What could it be?
Here the complete view:
@model BookVM
@{
    //true si la vista es para hacer un UPDATE y false si es para hacer un CREATE
    bool isUpdate = Model.Book.Id != 0 ? true:false;
}

<div class="row pb-2">
    <h2 class="text-primary">@(isUpdate ? "Update" : "Create") Book</h2>
    <hr />
</div>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    <div class="boder p-3 mb-4">
        
        <input asp-for="Book.Id" hidden />

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Book.Title"></label>
            <input asp-for="Book.Title" type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Book.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Book.Description"></label>
            <input asp-for="Book.Description" type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Book.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Book.ISBN"></label>
            <input asp-for="Book.ISBN" type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Book.ISBN" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Book.Author"></label>
            <input asp-for="Book.Author" type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Book.Author" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Book.ListPrice"></label>
            <input asp-for="Book.ListPrice" type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Book.ListPrice" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Book.Price"></label>
            <input asp-for="Book.Price" type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Book.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Book.Price50"></label>
            <input asp-for="Book.Price50" type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Book.Price50" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Book.Price100"></label>
            <input asp-for="Book.Price100" type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Book.Price100" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Book.CategoryId">Category</label>
            <select asp-for="Book.CategoryId" asp-items="@Model.CategoryOptions" class="form-select">
                <option disabled selected>--- select category</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <label asp-for="Book.ImageUrl"></label>
        </div>
 
        <div class="row">
            @if(isUpdate)
            {
                <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Update</button>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Create</button>
                </div>
            }
            
            <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary form-control" asp-controller="Book" asp-action="Index">
                    <i class="bi bi-arrow-left-circle"></i>Back
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
}

This is the field:

I do not add the controller because the flow of the app does not gets till that part.
I tried to watch the JS console in the browser, but it does not show anything, too I tried to add a break point in the controller but as I mentioned the flow of the application does not gets till that further.
It's pretty weird that just clicking the upload button, picking the image and clicking the ok button and just after that the application stops.
I'm using Brave web browser.

Post the (relevant) error you're getting. Check in the browser console and look if there is a request being made to the server. Maybe it's just a client side error, but it could trigger a server side problem. Since we don't have the code we can't know.

"just clicking the upload button, picking the image and clicking the ok button and just after that the application stops" - Do you mean that the browser freezes or in some way becomes unresponsive when you simply select a file for a file input element?  Does the problem occur in other browsers as well?  Unless there's other code which responds to that event client-side and is in some way failing, this doesn't sound like a problem with the code.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

It was a Brave web browser problem, I just tried Chrome and worked.
